# Tensorflow not displaying the right amount of free memory

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, ram

I've been trying to run a neural network of mine on my GPU but for some reason upon creating the device, Tensorflow won't see the full RAM memory and instead focuses on a 2GB free memory available...

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-05-25 11:00:56.992852: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this Ten
sorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-05-25 11:00:57.307883: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Quadro K620 major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.124
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
totalMemory: 2.00GiB freeMemory: 1.77GiB
2018-05-25 11:00:57.307883: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-05-25 11:00:59.637116: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with s
trength 1 edge matrix:
2018-05-25 11:00:59.638116: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2018-05-25 11:00:59.638116: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2018-05-25 11:00:59.644117: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhos
t/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1331 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Quadro K620, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
```

The GPU is a Quadro K620 on a Windows 7 with (according to task manager) 16GB of RAM. But upon looking in the Nvidia panel, it apparently has 10GB of available memory and only 2GB of dedicated video memory (I guess TF is using this part of the RAM instead of the rest). It is pretty annoying because I always end up running out of memory really quickly...

Can someone shed light on what is going on and why is TF doing that?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with TF. Your graphics card has exactly 2GB of DDR3 RAM. I think you are confusing GPU RAM with your CPU RAM which might be indeed 16 GB.

Answer (score 0):

You only have 2gb of gpu ram: https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/quadro-k620.c2600